# Does class ThreadInfo provide more information than reachable from JVMTI?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvmti

This is confusing. The [ThreadInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html) class provides alot of information, especially statistic of a Thread. However I cannot find such functions in the [JVMTI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html). Is this norma? Do I have to gather the data myself? Do I have to iterate to the ThreadInfo object myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the information available in the ThreadInfo class can be acquired through JVMTI functions:

See:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetThreadState

It's everything that's in ThreadInfo, just jammed into a bit vector.

Comment: This looks good, however I cannot see that data is gathered like ThreadInfo.getWaitedTime()